# Getting size of void* for creating a simple generic dynamically allocated array - C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

I have created a simple dynamic array in C.

```
typedef struct varray_t
{
    void **memory;
    size_t allocated;
    size_t used;
    int index;              
} varray;

void
varray_init(varray **array)
{
    *array = (varray*) malloc (sizeof(varray));    
    (*array)->memory = NULL;
    (*array)->allocated = 0;
    (*array)->used = 0;
    (*array)->index = -1;
}

void
varray_push(varray *array, void *data, size_t size)
{
    if ((array->allocated - array->used) < size) {
        array->memory = realloc(array->memory, array->allocated + size);
        array->allocated = array->allocated + size;
    }

    array->used = array->used + size;   
    array->memory[++array->index] = data;
}

int
varray_length(varray *array)
{
    return array->index + 1;
}

void
varray_clear(varray *array)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < varray_length(array); i++)
    {
        array->memory[i] = NULL;
    }    
    array->used = 0;
    array->index = -1;
}

void 
varray_free(varray *array)
{
    free(array->memory);
    free(array);
}

void*
varray_get(varray *array, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > array->index)
        return NULL;

    return array->memory[index];
}
```

This is working fine. But to add an item into the array, caller has to pass in the size of the element getting added. I can't figure out another way to get the size from the passed in `void*`. I am wondering is there a better way to design `varray_push(varray *array, void *data, size_t size)` so that `size` can be infered?

Any help would be great

**Edited code after the suggestions**

My array will contain only pointer elements. I have modified the code according to Blastfurnace's suggestion. New code will use `sizeof(void*)` and resize memory by a constant propotion to get amortized constant time on inserts.

```
void
varray_push(varray *array, void *data)
{
    size_t toallocate;
    size_t size = sizeof(void*);
    if ((array->allocated - array->used) < size) {
        toallocate = array->allocated == 0 ? size : (array->allocated * 2);
        array->memory = realloc(array->memory, toallocate);
        array->allocated = array->allocated + toallocate;
    }

    array->memory[++array->index] = data;
    array->used = array->used + size;
}
```

Comment: If the array only contains elements of one type, you can specify its size in `varray_init`. I wouldn't call it a better option, but then again, better at what?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: that's not a bad idea. Because array will contain only one type at a time. Thanks..

Comment: Your array just contains pointers. Isn't every element just `sizeof(void*)`?

Comment: Blastfurnace: You are right. I never thought about it. sizeof(void*) works

Comment: @Appu, but if you are going to store only pointer to each element, then who takes the ownership for creating, maintaining and freeing each of those elements? Because, in your varray_free also you are not freeing each of the elements, seperately.

Comment: @Appu that is an unsafe realloc call; if the allocation fails, you leak memory. Just FYI.

Comment: @Jay: My application uses a pool to keep the instances of the struct. Pool will take the ownership of those instances and clean it up when necessary. This array is generic and holds any pointers and won't care about ownership. The pool implementation internally uses this array.

Comment: @tbert: Thanks. I am aware of the problems. Actual production code checks for error conditions. I just removed it while posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is going to contain only one type at a time, then you can store the size of the type of the array in varray_init.

Also, my suggestion is that instead of allocating memory fresh for each element, you can allocate memory for constant size each time, i.e. first allocate memory for 16 elements and then when you find that array is full when pushing an element realloc for 16 + 16 = 32 elements. In this way, you can avoid calling malloc again and again and also it is not good idea to keep mallocing for small size data seperately.

EDIT:
After considering Blastfurnace comment, I feel that you should actually be doing a memcpy of the data rather than assignment if your intention is to store the data and not the pointer to the data.

Comment: Instead of growing by a constant amount, it's more efficient to use a geometric progression like `current_size * 2`. This gives you [amortized constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) for inserting new elements.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I edited the code to accodomadate changes mentioned by you. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple to use linked list implementation that you can use. I wouldn't say it is text book quality but it is easy: https://github.com/inorton/xrlist

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xrlist.h"

xr_list_t * mylist = xrlist_new();

xrlist_push(mylist, (void*) ptr1);
xrlist_push(mylist, (void*) ptr2);
```

You iterate like so:-

```
xr_list_item_t * iter = mylist->head;
while ( iter != NULL ) 
{
  printf(" * item [0x%x] contains [%s]\n",
    (unsigned int) iter->object, (char*) iter->object );
  iter = iter->next; 
}
```

You also have the usual remove/add/free functions too. See **[more examples here](https://github.com/inorton/xrlist/blob/master/tests/list.c)**.

If you want random access data like a dictionary you can also try out https://github.com/inorton/xrhash

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I was wondering if its possible to specify the range of an array you would want to push into another array. So for example like in C# someArray.AddRange(otherArray.Skip(6).Take(30));

Comment: @Stavros_S be my guest :)